# firebase for Web how get data in unique key(push())

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I have no idea how do I get the data("age") in unique key(generated by push())

Here is my code

```
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref('test');
    var a = dbRef.push().set({name: "apple", age: "12", sex: "male"});

    dbRef.on('value', snap => {
        console.log(snap.val()); //I want to get age: "12" !! 
    });
```

Here is the output(from console)

```
Object { -Kfq7woK-DmUsZ728lgF: Object }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log(snap.val().age);
```

By doing snap.val() you get the entire JavaScript object. Just add .age to get the "age" property.

You may read some documentation on Objects, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects of https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref('test');
var a = dbRef.push().set({name: "apple", age: "12", sex: "male"});

dbRef.on('child_added', snap => {
    console.log(snap.val()); //I want to get age: "12" !! 
    console.log(snap.val().age); //I want to get age: "12" !! 
});
```

It was the answer what I wannted thank you all!